# Handling undefined or null with ? throws SyntaxError: Unexpected token using webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs

I have handled undefined using ? on various places in my code. Earlier the code was directly added to html using the script tag. On browser the code works fine. Now am using webpack for my build process.

But I am getting following error while building:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (57:29)

  55 |     computed: {       
  56 |         userRole(){
> 57 |             return this.user?.role || 'N/A';
```

inside my webpack config, module is:

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  }
```

I am using `es2015` preset also. Any idea how can i fix this...

Thans in advance

Comment: Well, the `?.`  operator is not part of ES2015.

Comment: I believe it is a stage 3 proposal. 
But as it works on chrome browser, is there any way to use & compile using babel? I have used stage 3 preset on .babelrc, but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to fix the optional chaining operator issue.

I have update dependencies in the package.json as following

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.3.0",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.10.3"
  }
```

& My webpack configuration is

```
module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining"]
          }
        },
      },
    ],
  },
```

Earlier I was using `babel-cli`, `babel-core` & so on. After changing to `@babel/...` & also the babel-loader to >8 made thing works. Babel-loader is very important here.